# Information messages in XMPP MUC

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I'm looking for system that let me to put aditional system messages in MUC. For example 'chat room has been created', 'user1 has added user2' or 'user1 has left the room' etc. What is the best solution for that kind of messages?

Thanks

Comment: Just sent it with its own protocol like the normal messages. When someone creates a room, leaves it, changes affiliation, role, or subscribes they should send a corresponding message.

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy but I would like to have something like system message not message from the user

Comment: What do you mean by system message?  Like when you subscribe someone to a room, should the server automatically generate it? You can have events coming for those actions and build messages yourselves from those metadata.  https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/extensions/muc-sub/ can be helpful